# how to nest if and else statement using ternary operator in PHP?

Tags: php

am confused with using this ternary operator, i can easily get 1 level if and else
e.g

```
($blah == $blah) ? blahblah : blahblahblah;
```

but what if the condition is like this?

```
if($blah == blah1)
{ 
  echo $blah1;
}
else if($blah == blah2)
{
 echo $blah2;
}
else
{
 echo $blah;
}
```

how to convert this using ternary operator ?

Comment: In your ternary example, `blahblahblah` will never get returned...

Comment: If you are confused by which the if and else in the ternary are, then why would you want to make it more difficult to read? Packing an alternatives tree into it won't make it less confusing to you.

Comment: You could go even further and have double-nested, just to make sure nobody can ever read your code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo $blah == 'blah1' ? $blah1 : ($blah == 'blah2' ? $blah2 : $blah); ?>
```

Notice how the `else` is wrapped in parenthesis. This can be done again and again, although it becomes confusing to read.

Answer (score 3):

Nested ternaries are a bad idea. They're provided for brevity. If you have nested conditions, you by definition do not have brevity.

Some folk don't even like their use when you have a concise statement. Personally I find the following more clear and readable than the `if`-based alternative.

```
echo $success ? 'Success' : 'Failure';
```

But I would hesitate to do anything more complex than that.

Comment: It's just an operator. If you are comfortable with it I don't see the problem.

Comment: I agree. Just because you can doesn't mean you should. Nested ternaries are impossible to read and impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1):

($blah == $blah1) ? $blah1 : (($blah == $blah2) ? $blah2 : $blah);

Answer (score 0):

It would become:

```
echo (($blah == $blah1) ? $blah1 : (($blah == blah2) ? $blah2 : $blah);
```